# How to deepscan object values including children arrays

Tags: typescript, iteration

I'm trying to get all values of an object. Object also includes arrays and those array of objects contain arrays.

```
const iterate = (obj) => {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
        console.log(`key: ${key}, value: ${obj[key]}`)

        if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
            iterate(obj[key])
        }
    })
}
```

Currently it only shows the "higher level" objects

For example if I have a

```
class foo;
a: string;
b: string;
c SomeObject[];
```

The SomeObject part is always just a "Object". But I need the values of those objects too.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Generally it is helpful to make sure that code in questions constitutes a [mcve] so that others can easily see what your issue is.  In this case, it's not clear what you mean by "higher level" objects.  Can you include an example object and what you expect to see versus what you actually see?  Good luck!

Comment: It works. What do you mean by "only higher level object?" What should be returned in this case: iterate({ a: 'a', b: { c: 'c', d: 'd' }})

Comment: Updated main post

Answer (score 0):

Just check if it is an array and handle it specially:

```
const iterate = (obj) => {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
        const value = obj[key];
        console.log(`key: ${key}, value: ${value}`)

        if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
            for (let arrayItem of obj) {
                iterate(arrayItem);
            }
        }

        else if (typeof value === 'object') {
            iterate(value)
        }
    })
}
```

This should work for all JSON literals but won't work intuitively for things like sets or maps.

Comment: This works great for the most common use cases where JSON data is quite small and not deeply nested. For a 10MB JSON file it is far too slow to be practical and blows out the default HEAP size due to over recursion and node's lack of tail call recursion optimization.